# How to store input in session Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, session

I'm new in Laravel Here I am trying to post my input form in to a session but its not working I get this error without any message:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

I found nothing, here I am sharing some of my code.

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use \App\Product;

class ShopController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
        return view('shop.index', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function category($id)
    {
        $products = Category::find($id)->products;
        return view('shop.1', compact('products'));
    }

    public function addToShoppingCart(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('cart', 'id');
        $request->session()->put('cart', 'number');

        $request->session()->flash('status', 'Product is toegevoegd!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @if(Session::has('id', 'number'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{Session::get('id', 'number')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <ul>
            <li>{{ $product->name }}</li>
            <li>{{ $product->description }}</li>
            <li>{{ $product->price }}</li>
            <li>{{ $product->amount }}</li>
        </ul>
        <form method="post" action="{{url('categories\{id}')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="number">Aantal:</label>
                <input type="number" name="number">

                <label for="id">Id:</label>
                <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value= {{$product->id}}>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add product</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    @endforeach
    {{var_dump(Session::get('cart'))}}

@endsection
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/shop', 'Shopcontroller@index')->name('shop');
Route::get('/categories/{id}', 'ShopController@category');
Route::get('/cart/{id}', 'ShopController@addToShoppingCart');
```

I hope someone can help me out with my problem to put the input in the session of laravel.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to "post" using a "get" route. You should change `Route::get` by `Route::post`

Comment: Changed my $request to session en my post to get but still getting the same error

Comment: I was talking about your routes : 
`Route::get('/categories/{id}', 'ShopController@category');` 
become
`Route::post('/categories/{id}', 'ShopController@category');`

Comment: No error so thats great.

But my var_dump is not working do I need to change it to `{{var_dump(Session::get('number'))}}`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i suggest you use the `route()` method. There is nothing wrong with the `url()` method but i just using the `route()` method.

**So let's solve your problem out!**

## 1. Add names to your routes and set the ROUTE to POST instead of GET

```
Route::get('/shop', 'Shopcontroller@index')->name('shop');
Route::post('/categories/{id}', 'ShopController@category')->name('category');
Route::get('/cart/{id}', 'ShopController@addToShoppingCart')->name('cart.add');
```

## 2. Pass your route as an action to your form

```
action="{{route('category',['id' => 'your_category_id_here'])}}
```

## 3. Add `use Session;`

Your controller is missing the `use Session;` statement, add it on the top of the controller page so you can be able to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

bro your code is not correct at all. I had some problems like these too but then i read about sessions in laravel, global session access and using `session()->put($key)` is different and could get you problems, always debug using `dd($statements)` to know what your code output really is. Check this code and read it carefully :

in `web.php` :

```
//show cart

Route::get('/cart', [Products::class, 'showCart']);

// change quantity of a product in cart page

Route::post('/cart/{id}', [Products::class, 'changeQuantity']);

// remove product from cart

Route::delete('/cart/{id}', [Products::class, 'removeFromCart']);

//add to cart

Route::post('/singleProduct/{id}', [Products::class, 'addToCart']);
```

in Products controller :

```
//add to cart

public function addToCart(Request $request, $id)
{
    if (auth()->user()) {
        $products = product::find($id);
        $allColumns = $products->getAttributes();
        $getColumn = Session::get('quantity-' . $allColumns['id']);
        
        if (!$getColumn) {
            session()->put($request->input());
            return back()->with('message', 'Product added to cart');
        } else {
            return back()->with('message', 'Product already exists in cart');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}

//show cart
public function showCart()
{
    if (auth()->user()) {
        return view('cart', [
            'products' => product::all()
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}

// change quantity of a product in cart page
public function changeQuantity(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = product::find($id);
    $allColumns = $products->getAttributes();
    
    session()->pull('quantity-' . $allColumns['id']);
    session()->put($request->input());
    return back()->with('message', 'quantity updated');
}

//remove product from cart
public function removeFromCart(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = product::find($id);
    $allColumns = $products->getAttributes();

    session()->pull('quantity-' . $allColumns['id']);
    return back()->with('message', 'Product removed from cart');
}
```

in `singleProduct.blade.php` :

```
<img src="/storage/{{$product->logo}}" alt="product_image">  
<p>name: {{$product->name}}</p>
<p>tags: {{$product->tags}}</p>
<p>description: {{$product->description}}</p>
<p>price: {{$product->price}}</p><br>
            
<form action="/singleProduct/{{$product->id}}" method="POST">       
    @csrf

    <label for="quantity-{{$product->id}}">quantity</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" name="quantity-{{$product->id}}" value=1>
    <be>
    <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

in `cart.blade.php` :

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @if(Session::has('quantity-' . $product->id))

    @php
    $quantity = Session::get('quantity-' . $product->id);
    @endphp

        <p>name: {{$product->name}}</p>
        <p>description: {{$product->description}}</p>
        <p>tags: {{$product->tags}}</p>
        <p>price: {{$product->price}}</p>
        <label for="quantity-{{$product->id}}">quantity</label>

        <form method="POST" action="/cart/{{$product->id}}">
            @csrf

            <input type="number" min="1" name="quantity-{{$product->id}}" value="{{$quantity}}">
            <button type="submit">update</button>
        </form>

        <form method="POST" action="/cart/{{$product->id}}">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit">remove</button>
        </form>         

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: When providing answers, it helps if you explain any code changes or any code snippets.